# Windows Service Stopped working code 1053

Tags: windows, service, windows-10, windows-services

I have windows service installed and it's been working properly for months, suddenly it stopped with the code 1053 after searching I found out that by adding the following line in the config file of the service:

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
```

it's back working with no problem , no change in the service code was made we didn't deliver anything nor touched the web config and I checked windows updates and there was no updated prior to the stoppage of the service , anybody have a logical explanation or a suggestion of what happened ? I need to understand what went on ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it's a crash of .NET framework, can you try to re-install it ?
Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt that because the problem happened in three different environment I don't know if it's the same exact moment or no   .. but when we discovered the issue .. it was in the three.